# Python 3 Error using Full Contact API - Getting a TypeError

Tags: python, api, webhooks

I'm trying to subscribe to a person using Full Contact's Web Hooks, but when I run the code, I get this error.

TypeError: POST data should be bytes, an iterable of bytes, or a file object. It cannot be of type str.

I've tried to run it with UTF-8 encoding

```
import urllib.request, json

req = urllib.request.Request('https://api.fullcontact.com/v3/person.subscribe')
req.add_header('Authorization', 'Bearer {my api key}')
data = json.dumps({
    "email": "bart@fullcontact.com",
    "twitter": "@bartlorang",
    "fullName": "Bart Lorang",
    "webhookUrl": "http://www.fullcontact.com/hookUrl"
})

response = urllib.request.urlopen(req,data)
```